# Jasmine: mocking $animate from Angular Material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to mock the `$animate` service within a Jasmine unit test. The directive that I have under test is the following:

```
angular
    .module('splashDirective', ['ngMaterial'])
    .directive('mAppLoading', ['$animate', function($animate) {

    var link = function(scope, element, attributes) {

        $animate.leave(element.children().eq(1)).then(
            function cleanupAfterAnimation() {
                element.remove();
                scope = element = attributes = null;
            }
        );

   };

   return ({
       link: link,
       restrict: "C"
   });
}]);
```

It is a very easy one that only waits for the `cleanUpAfterAnimation()`, so that it removes itself from the DOM tree.

I am trying to test it with Jasmine + Karma with the following code:

```
describe('Testing Splash directive', function () {

    var $rootScope, $scope, $q,
        $compile,
        $directive,
        $body = $("body"),
        mock__animate = {
            leave: function () {
                return $q.when();
            }
        },
        html =
        "<div class='m-app-loading' ng-animate-children>" +
        "   <div class='animated-container'>" +
        "       <div class='messaging'>" +
        "           <h2>Test</h2>" +
        "       </div>" +
        "   </div>" +
        "</div>";

    beforeEach(function () {

        module('splashDirective', function ($provide) {
            $provide.value('$animate', mock__animate);
        });

        inject(function ($injector) {

            $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
            $compile = $injector.get('$compile');
            $q = $injector.get('$q');

            $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            $directive = $compile(angular.element(html))($scope);

        });

        $body.append($directive);
        $rootScope.$digest();

    });

    it('should compile the directive', function () {
        var div_directive = $("div.m-app-loading");
        expect(div_directive.length).toBe(1);
    });
});
```

However, the test fails since it looks like there is something wrong with the compilation of the HTML.

I have the following plnkr running that shows the exception:[example](http://plnkr.co/edit/0cOZQZ?p=preview)

What am I doing wrong? What is the correct way of mocking up `$animate`?

Comment: PS: To benefit future visitors, you might want to make some small edits to your question. The problem was less to do w/mocking `$animate` and more to do w/setting up the test for a directive. I think your approach for mocking `$animate` is fine ... depending on what you're trying to do you might even be able to use the real `$animate` service and spy on one of it's methods instead. But I'd do whatever is easiest :)

Comment: yeah this is a very bad title, and it is cross posted on a bunch of forums

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your plunkr, there are a several problems:

1. Your Plunkr throws an error b/c you have mis-matched module names.
   In your HTML you do `ng-app="plunkr"` but in your code you define
   the module name as "splashDirective". These names should be the
   same:

   ```
   <html ng-app="splashDirective">
   ```
2. Your test tries to get the `<body>` element from the page in the
   `beforeEach()` function. This was not working (you were getting an
   empty array). So calling `$body.append($directive)` was doing
   nothing at all. Your test will pass if you retrieve and populate the
   body inside an actual test (inside an `it()` function):

   ```
   it('should compile the directive', function () {
       $body = $("body");
       $body.append($directive);
       var div_directive = $("div.m-app-loading");
       expect(div_directive.length).toBe(1);
   });
   ```
3. You'll find that when your unit tests add elements to the body
   of the page, that they will remain on the page for the
   rest of that test run. This could affect other tests. You should use
   an `afterEach()` to clean up after each test is run:

   ```
   afterEach(function() {
       // sorry this is just from memory, please verify the syntax
       body.remove($directive);
   });
   ```

Here's a [fixed version](http://plnkr.co/edit/tOczpC1unko6mg2PAl2Q?p=preview) of your plunkr.

Comment: That fixed the problem! I just got two questions: 1) chrome reports this exception: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'env' of undefined", and 2) when adding "afterEach(function () { $body.empty(); });" I get a new exception: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null"... Jasmine is not throwing any more details about those exceptions, any ideas? I have included the modification in this plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/xBoPdD?p=preview

Comment: It is strange, maybe something related to executing Jasmine over HTML. I "patched" the code on my computer with your fixes, included the "afterEach" sentence with "$body.empty()" and Karma-Jasmine executes the tests correctly.